# Cancel node-schedule event after it has been set

Tags: node.js, cron

I am planning on using [node-schedule](https://github.com/tejasmanohar/node-schedule) to set up push notifications for appointment reminders as follows:

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var date = req.body.date;   // Date for reminder from client request 
var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
    // Send push notification
});
```

Now I know you can cancel the event by calling cancel():

```
j.cancel()
```

However, how can I refer to that specific job to cancel if the user from the client side decides to change the appointment to a different date?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In order to retrieve a specific job, you could create it with a unique name and you can retrieve it later via that unique name:

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob(unique_name, date, function() {
});
// later on
var my_job = schedule.scheduledJobs[unique_name];
my_job.cancel();
```

Comment: this worked beautifully.  thank you. i was trying to serialize the job object, write it into my db, retrieve it, deserialize it and the call .cancel(). you can imagine my pain.

Comment: \0/ that's awesome!

Comment: It is very helpful after 2 years as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ShahNewazKhan it seems it doesn't work with  node-schedule version 1.3.2. if there is a unique_name parameter, function is not called at specified date at all. with which version it works? also i can't find unique name as first parameter in doc.

Comment: `var j` is required?  I got `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cancel')`

Answer (score 1):

```
var randf = require('randomstring');    
    var jobId = randf.generate(10); //randomsrting
    var at = new Date();
    var time = at.setSeconds(at.getSeconds() + Number(5))  //after 5 second     
    schedule.scheduleJob(jobId, new Date(time),function(){
         schedule.cancelJob(jobId);
         console.log('hi--viral');
     });
```