# Cannot read property 'cancel' of undefined - node-schedule

Tags: node.js, node-schedule

nodejs tells me 
**Cannot read property 'cancel' of undefined**
when i want to exectue job.cancel()

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');


test = schedule.scheduleJob({second: 2, hour: 
dataA[0].on_h , minute: dataA[0].on_m, dayOfWeek: 
timerSD.day}, function(){ 
    console.log(now+': Timer automatic ON  - SD: '+x+ "timer ID"+dataA[0].ID);
    db.setStatus(x, 1);
});
test.cancel();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancel node-schedule event after it has been set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113287/cancel-node-schedule-event-after-it-has-been-set)

Answer (score 0):

I do a workaround with reschedule. This works:

```
test = schedule.scheduleJob({second: 3, hour: dataA[0].off_h , minute: dataA[0].off_m, dayOfWeek: timerSD.day}, function() {
                console.log(now+': Timer automatic OFF - SD: '+x+ "timer ID."+dataA[0].ID);
                db.setStatus(x, 0);
            });
test.reschedule(true);
```

Comment: unfortunatly my workaround was wrong.. this ist not working:(